# File upload timeouts with Ruby on Rails and apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timeout, file-upload

I have a rails application running under 2.3.4 and Ubuntu. I'm using passenger.

I have had complaints when users try to upload large files (>300MB). For my part, I can do it just fine, but I have a very fast internet connection.

What's more puzzling is the behavior they see on their end. At some point into the process the upload process appears to hang. They don't receive an error, but if they look at their network traffic, nothing is happening.

Is this possibly an apache setting? Or could it be something on their end? Any suggestions on where I should look would be greatly appreciated.

Bob

Answer (score 1):

If its timepout problem then look in to apche's httpd.conf file and try to set  Keepalive on parameter

Answer (score 0):

In php its called max post size, I'm not really savvy with ruby but I would think its something along those lines. A 300mb upload is quite a large file to handle over HTTP POST.

Answer (score 0):

Setting KeepAlive to On solved the problem for me.
I was adjusting the Timeout setting which worked, but isn't the best idea.

My uploads weren't as large though ( only about 3-5mb ). 
Did the KeepAlive help you on the 300mb Bob?

Mine is also a rails app, for this problem the app type isn't the issue.